# json application only executed from the android studio

Tags: android, json, android-volley

How are you?

I have build in the last couple of days my new jSon application.
It takes params on earthquak from this website 
https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php

And it works great. but only when I executed it from the google studio.
If I then close the app and open it manually on my phone, I do not see any data at all.

I mean the app is opening but no json data. Just blank Screen, not textVIew nor listView nothing.

I do use the following in the MainActivity.

```
package com.example.erang.jsonsample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Network;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createJsonRequest();




        // Create an {@link EarthQukeAdapter}, whose data source is a list of {@link earthquake}s. The
        // adapter knows how to create list items for each item in the list.
        EarthQuakeAdapter adapter = new EarthQuakeAdapter(this, earthquakes);

// Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
        // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
        // earthquake_activity.xml layout file.
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link WordAdapter} we created above, so that the
        // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link earthquake} in the list.
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }

    public void createJsonRequest() {

// Instantiate the cache
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap

// Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

// Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
        RequestQueue mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

// Start the queue
        mRequestQueue.start();

        String url = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_month.geojson";

// Formulate the request and handle the response.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //Passing the response
                        parseJsonRequest(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    public void parseJsonRequest(String response) {


        if (response != null) {
            // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
            try {
                JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray features = reader.getJSONArray("features");
                for(int index=0;index<features.length();index++){
                    JSONObject properties = reader.getJSONArray("features").getJSONObject(index).getJSONObject("properties");
                    Double magnitude = properties.getDouble("mag");
                    String place = properties.getString("place");
                    String url = properties.getString("url");
                    //This split between offset location and primary location
                    String[] separated = place.split(",");
                        //If there is missing field jump to the next item
                        if(separated.length < 2){
                            continue;
                        }
                        //This contain the offsetLocation
                        String offsetLocation = separated[0];
                        //This contain the primaryLocation
                        separated[1] = separated[1].trim();
                        String primaryLocation = separated[1];
                    //Passing date twice one for the date and one for the time.
                    String updateDate = properties.getString("time");
                    java.util.Date date=new java.util.Date(Long.valueOf(updateDate) );
                     //The second date passing the time
                    earthquakes.add(new Earthquake(magnitude, offsetLocation, primaryLocation, date, date, url));

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
                // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
                // with the message from the exception.
                Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see I am using the following volley package for doing all json stuff.
Further digging to my phone using catlog I see the following line when open manually the app.

```
ApplicationPolicy:IsApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 

dalvikvm> >>>>com.example.erang.jsonsample[userid:0|appId:10216]
```

Any idea why I am seen my app runing well only when executed from the android Studio.

In Manifest File I have also added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Many Thanks in Advance.

Eran

Comment: Why it would be null.? First I am not getting any Exception. second I populate the array on this line                     earthquakes.add(new Earthquake(magnitude, offsetLocation, primaryLocation, date, date, url));
Why it works great when executed from the Studio and be different when executed manually ?

Comment: I have edited you question, try may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();
EarthQuakeAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createJsonRequest();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

public void createJsonRequest() {

// Instantiate the cache
    Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap

// Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
    Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

// Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
    RequestQueue mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

// Start the queue
    mRequestQueue.start();

    String url = "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_month.geojson";

// Formulate the request and handle the response.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //Passing the response
                    parseJsonRequest(response);

                    adapter = new EarthQuakeAdapter(MainActivity.this, earthquakes);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // Handle error
                }
            });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}

public void parseJsonRequest(String response) {


    if (response != null) {
        // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
        try {
            JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray features = reader.getJSONArray("features");
            for(int index=0;index<features.length();index++){
                JSONObject properties = reader.getJSONArray("features").getJSONObject(index).getJSONObject("properties");
                Double magnitude = properties.getDouble("mag");
                String place = properties.getString("place");
                String url = properties.getString("url");
                //This split between offset location and primary location
                String[] separated = place.split(",");
                //If there is missing field jump to the next item
                if(separated.length < 2){
                    continue;
                }
                //This contain the offsetLocation
                String offsetLocation = separated[0];
                //This contain the primaryLocation
                separated[1] = separated[1].trim();
                String primaryLocation = separated[1];
                //Passing date twice one for the date and one for the time.
                String updateDate = properties.getString("time");
                java.util.Date date=new java.util.Date(Long.valueOf(updateDate) );
                //The second date passing the time
                earthquakes.add(new Earthquake(magnitude, offsetLocation, primaryLocation, date, date, url));

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
            // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
            // with the message from the exception.
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: One issue with your sample is the 
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
Which define in the onCreate and it does not recongnize in the OnResponse.
But I missing the line of the creation of the array you remove it entirely

Comment: otherwise just do one thing, In your code after parseJsonRequest(response); add this line  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Did not help...but thanks for the effort Mohammad., :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem.
First I was looking on another implementation using Async and I saw there is onPostExecute method which runs on post execute.
As I am using volley I looked for something similar.
And I understood that I need to use OnResponse method.
So I switched my 3 lines of code.

```
@Override
 public void onResponse(String response) {
//Passing the response
parseJsonRequest(response);

EarthQuakeAdapter adapter = new EarthQuakeAdapter(MainActivity.this, earthquakes);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
},
```

In to the OnResponse so only after the array is populated I will create the adapter and add it to the list view.